# .net Provider model and 3-tier architecture

Tags: asp.net, .net, 3-tier, provider-model

I couldn't find a clear enough (for me) explanation of the `.net` Provider model (does it have a different name in 'classic' design pattern texts?), but from what I gathered, it seems to be a natural fit for 3-tier architecture, with the DAL and BL each being a provider for the layer above.
If I am correct in my understanding, can anyone point me to an example that actually does this? I could find very little sample material on Providers that wasn't about how to extend the user/role thingy to another backend. The little I did find had nothing to do with 3-tiers.

If there is an example targeting specifically ASP.NET, that is even better.

Comment: You might want to read this. http://www.amazon.com/Professional-ASP-NET-Security-Membership-Management/dp/0764596985/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1367879545&sr=1-1&keywords=Professional+ASP.NET+2.0+Security%2C+Membership%2C+and+Role+Management

Comment: Read all this articles. They can help you alot.[3-tier architecture in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11128/3-tier-architecture-in-C)

[Building a 3-Tier Application using ASP.NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/paulabraham/building3tierapppa11282005053625am/building3tierapppa.aspx)

[3-Tier Architecture in ASP.NET with C#](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article71.aspx)